# Modify voting button alt text on Meta sites

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta, per-site-meta

We've had [yet another person get confused](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/should-we-create-a-community-wiki-on-what-is-plagiarism) by the nature of Meta voting. This guy proposed a pretty good idea, though... change the voting button alt text on Meta from the standard "shows research effort/clear & useful" to something that explains how voting works on Meta. My personal suggestion is "I (dis)agree with this concept/policy change", but I'm sure we can think of something better than that. Thoughts?

Comment: @animuson You've pointed to a five-year-old request lots of upvotes, with an accepted answer of "this is a good idea". Not sure what that means here...

Comment: It means it's a popular feature request that many people want, but that was formally declined by Stack Exchange. They will not do it, as explained by Jeff in his answer. To appeal the decision you can edit this request, mention that other request, and explain what changed and why you think it would be a good idea in spite of what Jeff said there.